# Regarding SSIS, Does the Lookup Tool Have Issues With Symbols?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Was just curious about the lookup tool and its ability to match on symbols.

I noticed that I have a record inside the warehouse as a varchar and it is something along the lines of "A & B"

I am doing a lookup inside SSIS and sending any no matches to be redirected somewhere else while I error handle. I noticed that only one record is not matching and that record is "A & B" which is definitely inside the warehouse. Is just a limitation with lookup and its ability to match symbols? I thought maybe there was some trailing characters after the "B" but that doesn't seem to be it either.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh I was able to find out the issue. So Lookup 100% works with symbols and it was a data issue from the source. Sorry about that! But yeah, if anyone is curious, having symbols would work :)